# how to test files in a specific folder and its sub-folder using Mocha?

Tags: typescript, firebase, mocha.js

Here is my project directory:

[image]

As you can see, there are two subfolders inside `tests` folder. I can run all test files inside `tests` folder using this command:

```
mocha -r ts-node/register src/**/*.test.ts --timeout 60000 --exit
```

But now I want only run tests for files inside `firestore_security_rules_test` folder, so I run this:

```
mocha -r ts-node/register src/tests/firestore_security_rules_tests/**/*.test.ts --timeout 60000 --exit
```

But if I run using this script, not all test files will be executed. here is the problem:

[image]

As you can see, inside `firestore_security_rules_test` folder, I have several folders. the script above only execute test files that located inside the first folder, in this case only execute files like events_security_rules.test.ts and users_security_rules.test.ts.

But, as you can see, inside `users` folder, there are more subfolders. The files inside the sub-folders of `users` folder will never be executed if run that mocha script above.

So how to test all files in a specific folder and also in its sub-folder using Mocha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`--recursive`](https://mochajs.org/#-recursive) and [`--extension`](https://mochajs.org/#-extension-ext) flags:

```
mocha -r ts-node/register src/tests/firestore_security_rules_tests \ 
      --recursive --extension .test.ts --timeout 60000 --exit
```